# How do i pass a class as an argument and then use a shared method of that class?

Tags: vb.net, class, arguments

NOTE: This question is NOT asking how to pass an *instance* of a class.  It is asking how to pass *the* class which has shared items.

For example ...
Any idea on how to make a function that will do this?

```
Public Function InsertSQL(ByVal xClass As Type) As String
    InsertSQL = "Insert into "
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & xClass.TableName
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & " ("
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & xClass.FieldList
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & " )"
End Function
```

With a set of classes like this:

```
Public Class cClient
    Public Shared TableName = "Clients"
    Public Shared Function FieldList() As String
        FieldList = "Name, Phone"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class cSale
    Public Shared TableName = "Sales"
    Public Shared Function FieldList() As String
        FieldList = "Name, Amount"
    End Function
End Class
```

I have search for "How to a pass a class as an argument" on Google, but have not found anything that addresses a way to access shared methods of the class.  I can only get results that think I am wanting to pass an instance of that class.

Note that this code is just an example.
And - of course, I have no problem if I pass an instance of a class.
But - that is not what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Use inheritance and no need to have Shared members when all of you class Inherits from a base class with the common functionality

Comment: In your function declare a string, make your insert statement on that string variable and return that string.

Comment: Shared variables, properties, functions, and sub routines mean they can be accessed without creating an instance of the class. The 2 classes only have shared stuff in them so you dont need to pass a instance of the class to InsertSql to be able to use the classes inside the function.

Comment: To all that have answered so far:

I have already stated: ", I have no problem if I pass an instance of a class. But - that is not what I am trying to figure out."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x4yd9d5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in your situation. 
Something like this

```
Public Sub Main
    Dim c = new cClient()
    Dim sql = InsertSQL(c)
    Console.WriteLine(sql)
End Sub


' Pass an actual instance of a class that inehrits cTableBase'
' all of these classes have the same BASE functions and property
' defined in the base class
Public Function InsertSQL(ByVal xClass As cTableBase) As String
    InsertSQL = "Insert into "
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & xClass.TableName
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & " ("
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & xClass.FieldList
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & " )"
End Function

Public Class cTableBase
    Public TableName As String 
    Public Overridable Function FieldList() As String
    End Function
End Class

Public Class cClient 
    Inherits cTableBase
    Public Sub New
        TableName = "Clients"
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function FieldList() As String
        FieldList = "Name, Phone"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class cSale 
    Inherits cTableBase
    Public Sub New
        TableName = "Sales"
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function FieldList() As String
        FieldList = "Name, Amount"
    End Function
End Class
```

As you have posted in the comment below. This could be done using the Type passed to the method InsertSQL using reflection

```
Sub Main
    Dim c = new cClient()
    Dim result = InsertSQL(c.GetType())
    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub

Public Function InsertSQL(ByVal xClass As Type) As String

    Dim fi = xClass.GetField("TableName")
    Dim tableName = fi.GetValue(xClass)

    Dim mi = xClass.GetMethod("FieldList")
    Dim fieldList = mi.Invoke(xClass, Nothing)

    InsertSQL = "Insert into "
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & tableName
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & " ("
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & fieldList
    InsertSQL = InsertSQL & " )"
End Function
```

Comment: I have already stated: ", I have no problem if I pass an instance of a class. But - that is not what I am trying to figure out."

Comment: Let me try something using reflection then

Comment: Added a different approach with reflection. A bit more complex

Comment: Interesting... So you have to basically dig out the ability to use the shared items.

Comment: Notice that you still need to have an instance to extract the Type to pass to InsertSQL. Still haven't found a way to pass directly the cClient class